# what is the difference between j=i+1 and j=1 if i=0 (in a nested for loop)?

Tags: java, for-loop

I don't understand the reason why the first for loop gives only one result, while the second gives me two results. Can someone explain to me how it works?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {5,5,11,15};
        int target = 10;
        System.out.print("First Solution: ");
        twoSum(array,target);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Second Solution: ");
        twoSum2(array,target);
    }

    public static void twoSum(int[] array, int target){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++){
                if(array[i] + array[j] == target){
                    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(new int[]{i, j}));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // if i want all the possible solutions
    public static void twoSum2(int[] array, int target){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < array.length; j++){
                if(array[i] + array[j] == target){
                    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(new int[]{i, j}));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

first output: [0, 1]
second output: [0, 1][1, 1]

Comment: For the first solution, the second for-loop only checks indices after the index i in the array. In the second solution, the second for-loop goes through all the indices in the array, regardless of what i is. That’s why the second output has 2 solutions; the array was being looped entirely for every i value

Comment: "if i=0 (in a nested for loop)" but `i` is not always 0. In second iteration of outer loop `i=1` (and inner loop of second version also starts from `1` which means at that time both loops will be *using* element at same index meaning `array[i] + array[j] == target` will represent `array[1]+array[1]=10` which is `5+5==10` -> `true`)

Comment: The condition should be:

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {

Answer (score 1):

The first finds all (i, j) such that j > i in approx. n*n/2 steps.

The second loop is probably long. If meant for (i, j) such that i ≠ j

```
public static void twoSum2(int[] array, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            if (j != i) {
                if (array[i] + array[j] == target) {
                    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(new int[]{i, j}));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This excludes (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), ...

However this takes approx. n² steps.
One could also take extend the first solution.

```
public static void twoSum2(int[] array, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
            if (array[i] + array[j] == target) {
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(new int[]{i, j}));
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(new int[]{j, i}));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: `Arrays.sort` may be used so you may start with largest fitting number. And `Arrays.binarySearch` to find `target - array[i]`.

Comment: The condition should be: for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {

Comment: @nvd of course there is no actual difference, as the _for-j_ loop in my last case will not be executed, but your suggestion gives more _intelligent_ code.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**

Your use case is to find pairs of elements in array that sum up to a target value

**What's happening in twoSum() method or j = i + 1 case**

As the inner loop starts with the immediately next index of the outer loop you are distinct pairs which are adding up to the desired value

**What's happening in twoSum2() method or j = 1 case**

As the inner loop starts with the index 1 every time regardless of the outer index value you are getting duplicate pairs which are adding up to the desired value along with an erroneous situation of a single element getting counted twice(I believe it's a bug and should be handled by an if condition check). Moreover, since it's starting from index 1 instead of 0 even all duplicates are not guaranteed. This approach should be avoided if my assumption of your use case is correct

**Recommendation**

Try exploring the Hashset based approach for this problem [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/). You can utilize the code or tweak it to match your use case. It's time complexity will be linear i.e. O(n) better than the current algorithm used in your code which is quadratic i.e. O(n^2)